# Push array inside another array in js?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in js that I want to fill using a for bucle.

To do this, I use this code:

```
var array = [];
var aux = [];
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    aux = [i,i+1,i+2];
    array.push({
       name:i,
       data:aux
    });

}
```

The issue is that the name is changed but the data key is overwritten, so I think that I have to push the data too, but don't know how.

Comment: *"bucle"* -> *loop*? What's the output you expected, and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that

```js
const array = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const aux = [];
    const quantity = i + 3;
    for (j = i; j < quantity; j++) {
        aux.push(j);
    }
    array.push({ name: i, data: aux });
}
```

Let me know if need some help or change